# Numpy Array Iteration, starting with third value

Tags: python, numpy, loops, iteration

I need to iterate through an numpy array, but I need to start with the third value.
My exact problem is the following.

I get an array like this:

```
data([0.0000, 1], [0.0011, 2], [0.0036, 3], ....)
```

I need to subtract the 0.0011 from 0.0036 and all the following values, from the first column.
I wanted to do something like this:

```
            data[:, 0] = data[:, 0] - data[1, 0]
```

But it needs to start with 0.0036 and not 0.0000. Could somebody maybe help me with this problem?

Comment: Should it be: `data[2:] - data[1, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate from index 2 and beyond, something like this:

```
for i, n in enumerate(data):
    if i < 2:
        continue
    data[:, 0] = data[i, 0] - data[i+1, 0]
```